# How to show sessions as count and percentage at the same time in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, metrics

I'm setting up a monthly dashboard report in Google Analytics and I'm finding the default metrics to be a little limited as far as what we want to see. I think I can make it work with some customization, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting there.

The first widget on the dashboard shows Sessions by Device Category. Three categories show on the table (desktop, tablet, mobile) and each shows the number of sessions for the selected date range. So far, so good. Now however, I need to add a third column that shows the percentage that number represents of the total.

I got as far as setting up a calculated metric, but there doesn't seem to be a metric for "Total Sessions" or the like.

**How do I set up a formula for the filtered # of sessions vs. the total?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashboard inside Google Analytics is not very flexible. For what you are trying to show, a pie chart may be more appropriate to show % split, either instead of or as well as the table.

Making dashboards in Data Studio is much more flexible.

Comment: Accepted! The pie chart option does what I need, as I can mouse over the percentage to see the actual number. Granted, that functionality disappears when exported to a PDF, but the percentage is still available via the obvious graphic representation. Thanks!